# Split list in two equal halves (±1)

Tags: elixir

I know I can split an *even* list in two equal halves in elixir by doing this:

```elixir
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
len = round(length(list) / 2)

[a, b] = Enum.chunk(list, len)            # => [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

but is there a *ruby-esque* method built-in or some more efficient way of doing this that also handles odd-length lists?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Enum.chunk_every/4](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#chunk_every/4) actually takes 4 arguments and will work with an odd length list if you include the 4th (`pad`) argument:

```ex
iex(14)> Enum.chunk_every([1,2,3,4,5], 3, 3, [])
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
```

Comment: In Elixir 1.5 Enum.chunk was renamed to [Enum.chunk_every](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Enum.html#chunk_every/4).

Answer (score 5):

After going through the docs, and searching elsewhere I still didn't find a built in solution, but I did come across [`Enum.split/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.1/elixir/Enum.html#split/2). This method seems like a better fit to divide odd-length lists but returns a `tuple` instead of a list of lists.

I still don't know how efficient this is.

**Example:**

```ex
def split(list) do
  len = round(length(list)/2)
  Enum.split(list, len)
end


split([1, 2, 3, 4])        # => {[1, 2], [3, 4]}
split([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])     # => {[5, 6, 7], [8, 9]}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is any "more idiomatic" way to do this.  I don't know of a built-in method to do this.

One suggestion--if you're dealing with larger lists, you may be better off to use a Stream rather than an Enum.

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
s = Stream.take_every(list,2)
l2 = Enum.to_list(s)  #=> [1,3,5,7,9]
```

And then

```
l1 = list -- l2 #=> [2,4,6,8]
```

You're better off to use a Stream where you can because a Stream is lazily evaluated.  In this particular case, it wouldn't make a difference.  But in some cases lazy evaluation can really speed things up.

As I say my code is no more idiomatic than your solution and it's certainly not a built-in function.